# Getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ....\asm-all-repackaged.jar

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, gradle

I am using:

- `springboot:2.1.6`
- `tomcat:9.0.22`
- `java : 9.0.4`

When doing bootRun i am getting errors like

> Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users.gradle...\asm-all-repackaged.jar

When checking my .gradle folder several of these jars are missing.
Could someone please explain why these jars are not getting downloaded.

I am using following dependency in my gradle file:

- compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed'
- name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper'
- version: '9.0.22'

This is so that i can test my jsp pages on a example.demo application

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.9'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

war {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.22'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Furthermore when accessing `localhost:8080` getting following error:

> Whitelabel error page , (type=not found, status=404)

Comment: Did you did clean and build after bootRun?

Comment: @JonathanJohx yes i did

Comment: Add jar {
    enabled = true
}

Comment: @Jonathan Johx ,just tried it, still same issue

Answer (score 0):

remove implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'